# I am getting a "TypeError: form is undefined" when I first load my page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, firefox

I am developing a form that i can transmit new hire data to our recruiting with JSON. I just started this but am also kinda new with Node.js and am testing as i go. Can you please let me know how i can stop this error from coming up.

Error:
TypeError: form is undefined http://localhost:63342/VAP_FORM/index.html:32:11

Browser: firefox

```js
/**
 * Retrieves input data from a form and returns it as a JSON object.
 * @param  {HTMLFormControlsCollection} elements  the form elements
 * @return {Object}                               form data as an object literal
 */
const formToJSON = elements => [].reduce.call(elements, (data, element) => {

    data[element.name] = element.value;
    return data;

}, {});
  /**
   * A handler function to prevent default submission and run our custom script.
   * @param  {Event} event  the submit event triggered by the user
   * @return {void}
   */

const handleFormSubmit = event => {

    event.preventDefault();

    const data = formToJSON(form.elements);

    const dataContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('results__display')[0];

    dataContainer.textContent = JSON.stringify(data, null, "  ");
    console.log(dataContainer);
};
/* We find the form element using its class name, then attach the
*  `handleFormSubmit()` function to the 
* `submit` event.
*/
const form = document.getElementsByClassName('contact-form')[0];
form.addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmit);
```

```css
.valid{
  border:1px solid blue;
}
.invalid{
  border:1px solid red;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}
.left{
  width: 10%;
}
.right {
  width: 30%;
}
.middle {
  width: 60%;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
}
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
#vapheading {
    color: black;
    font-family: Avenir;

}
#form{
    color: white;
    background-color: navy;
    padding: 16px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1026px) {
    #left,#right {
        display: none;
    }
}
input {
    border: 4px solid whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
select {
    border: 4px solid whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
body{
    background-color: lightgrey;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vap_css.css"/>
      <script src="vap_script.js"></script>
      <script>
        function validateForm() {
            var x = document.forms["myForm"]["ssn1"].value;
            var y = document.forms["myForm"]["ssn2"].value;
            if (x !== y ){
                alert("Social Security number does not match");
                return false;
            }

        }

      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column left" id="left"></div>
      <div class="column middle" id="middle">
        <h2 id = "vapheading">Please fill out the Following Form</h2>
          <div id = "form">
          <form class="contact-form__label" name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
            <table id = "table">
              <tr>
                  <td>First Name:* <br/><input type="text" name="firstname" id="fname" required/></td>
                  <td>Middle Name: <br/><input type="text" name="middlename" id="mname" /></td>
                  <td>Last Name:* <br/><input type="text" name="lastname" id="lname" required/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Suffix: <br/><input type="text" name="suffix" id="suffix" /></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
            <tr>
              <td>SSN:* <br/><input class="required-input" id="ssn1" maxlength="9" type="password" name="ssn1" required/></td>
              <td>Verify SSN:* <br/><input class="required-input" id="ssn2" maxlength="9" type="password" name="ssn2" required/></td>
              <td>Date of Birth:* <br/><input type="date" name="birthday"  id="bday" required/></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Place of Birth - City:* <br/><input type="text" name="city" id="city"  required/></td>
              <td>Place of Birth - State: <br/><input type="text" name="state"  id="state" ></td>
              <td>Place of Birth - Country:* <br/><select name="country"  id="country" required>
                <option value="">Choose Here</option>
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option><option value="Albania">Albania</option><option value="Algeria">Algeria</option><option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
                <option value="Angola">Angola</option><option value="Antigua & Deps">Antigua & Deps</option><option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
                <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option><option value="Australia">Australia</option><option value="Austria">Austria</option>
                <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option><option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option><option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
                <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option><option value="Barbados">Barbados</option><option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
                <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option><option value="Belize">Belize</option><option value="Benin">Benin</option>
                <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option><option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option><option value="Bosnia Herzegovina">Bosnia Herzegovina</option>
                <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option><option value="Brazil">Brazil</option><option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
                <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option><option value="Burkina">Burkina</option><option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
                <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option><option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option><option value="Canada">Canada</option>
                <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option><option value="Central African Rep">Central African Rep</option><option value="Chad">Chad</option>
                <option value="Chile">Chile</option><option value="China">China</option><option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
                <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option><option value="Congo">Congo</option><option value="Congo {Democratic Rep}">Congo {Democratic Rep}</option>
                <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option><option value="Croatia">Croatia</option><option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
                <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option><option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option><option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
                <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option><option value="Dominica">Dominica</option><option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
                <option value="East Timor">East Timor</option><option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option><option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
                <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option><option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option><option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
                <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option><option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option><option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
                <option value="Finland">Finland</option><option value="France">France</option><option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
                <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option><option value="Georgia">Georgia</option><option value="Germany">Germany</option>
                <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option><option value="Greece">Greece</option><option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
                <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option><option value="Guinea">Guinea</option><option value="Guinea-Bissau">Guinea-Bissau</option>
                <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option><option value="Haiti">Haiti</option><option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
                <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option><option value="Iceland">Iceland</option><option value="India">India</option>
                <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option><option value="Iran">Iran</option><option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
                <option value="Ireland {Republic}">Ireland {Republic}</option><option value="Israel">Israel</option><option value="Italy">Italy</option>
                <option value="Ivory Coast">Ivory Coast</option><option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option><option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option><option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option><option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
                <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option><option value="Korea North">Korea North</option><option value="Korea South">Korea South</option>
                <option value="Kosovo">Kosovo</option><option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option><option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                <option value="Laos">Laos</option><option value="Latvia">Latvia</option><option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
                <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option><option value="Liberia">Liberia</option><option value="Libya">Libya</option>
                <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option><option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option><option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
                <option value="Macedonia">Macedonia</option><option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option><option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
                <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option><option value="Maldives">Maldives</option><option value="Mali">Mali</option>
                <option value="Malta">Malta</option><option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option><option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
                <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option><option value="Mexico">Mexico</option><option value="Micronesia">Micronesia</option>
                <option value="Moldova">Moldova</option><option value="Monaco">Monaco</option><option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
                <option value="Montenegro">Montenegro</option><option value="Morocco">Morocco</option><option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
                <option value="Myanmar, {Burma}">Myanmar, {Burma}</option><option value="Namibia">Namibia</option><option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
                <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option><option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option><option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
                <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option><option value="Niger">Niger</option><option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
                <option value="Norway">Norway</option><option value="Oman">Oman</option><option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                <option value="Palau">Palau</option><option value="Panama">Panama</option><option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
                <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option><option value="Peru">Peru</option><option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
                <option value="Poland">Poland</option><option value="Portugal">Portugal</option><option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
                <option value="Romania">Romania</option><option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option><option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
                <option value="St Kitts & Nevis">St Kitts & Nevis</option><option value="St Lucia">St Lucia</option><option value="Saint Vincent & the Grenadines">Saint Vincent & the Grenadines</option>
                <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option><option value="San Marino">San Marino</option><option value="Sao Tome & Principe">Sao Tome & Principe</option>
                <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option><option value="Senegal">Senegal</option><option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
                <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option><option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option><option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
                <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option><option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option><option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
                <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option><option value="South Africa">South Africa</option><option value="South Sudan">South Sudan</option>
                <option value="Spain">Spain</option><option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option><option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
                <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option><option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option><option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
                <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option><option value="Syria">Syria</option><option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
                <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option><option value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option><option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
                <option value="Togo">Togo</option><option value="Tonga">Tonga</option><option value="Trinidad & Tobago">Trinidad & Tobago</option>
                <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option><option value="Turkey">Turkey</option><option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
                <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option><option value="Uganda">Uganda</option><option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
                <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option><option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option><option value="United States">United States</option>
                <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option><option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option><option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
                <option value="Vatican City">Vatican City</option><option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option><option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
                <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option><option value="Zambia">Zambia</option><option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
              </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Citizenship:* <br/><select name="citizenship"  id="citixen" default required>
                              <option value="">Choose Here</option>
                              <option value="USCitizen">US Citizen</option>
                              <option value="greencard">Green Card</option>
                              <option value="H1B">H1B</option>
                              <option value="EAD">EAD</option>
                              <option value="Other">Other</option>
                          </select></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <br/><br/><button type="submit">Submit</button>

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column right" id="right"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try placing your `vap_script.js` before the end of the body tag..

Comment: It looks like you are retrieving the form based on a class name of "contact-form", but the actual class on your form element is "contact-form__label", so the getElementByClassName isn't returning anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class name selector isn't working, use the full class name `contact-form__label` or you could use `getElementsByName` instead. However, also you are importing your script before the DOM has been loaded, so you will need to move the script import at the bottom of the body.

If for what ever reason you didn't want to move the script, you could wrap your form selection in an event listener will perform when the page conetnt is ready like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  let form = document.getElementsByClassName('contact-form__label')[0];
  form.addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmit);
});
```

```js
/**
 * Retrieves input data from a form and returns it as a JSON object.
 * @param  {HTMLFormControlsCollection} elements  the form elements
 * @return {Object}                               form data as an object literal
 */
const formToJSON = elements => [].reduce.call(elements, (data, element) => {

    data[element.name] = element.value;
    return data;

}, {});
  /**
   * A handler function to prevent default submission and run our custom script.
   * @param  {Event} event  the submit event triggered by the user
   * @return {void}
   */

const handleFormSubmit = event => {

    event.preventDefault();

    const data = formToJSON(form.elements);

    const dataContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('results__display')[0];

    dataContainer.textContent = JSON.stringify(data, null, "  ");
    console.log(dataContainer);
};
/* We find the form element using its class name, then attach the
*  `handleFormSubmit()` function to the 
* `submit` event.
*/
let form = document.getElementsByClassName('contact-form__label')[0];
form.addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmit);
```

```css
.valid{
  border:1px solid blue;
}
.invalid{
  border:1px solid red;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}
.left{
  width: 10%;
}
.right {
  width: 30%;
}
.middle {
  width: 60%;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
}
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
#vapheading {
    color: black;
    font-family: Avenir;

}
#form{
    color: white;
    background-color: navy;
    padding: 16px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1026px) {
    #left,#right {
        display: none;
    }
}
input {
    border: 4px solid whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
select {
    border: 4px solid whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
body{
    background-color: lightgrey;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vap_css.css"/>
      <script>
        function validateForm() {
            var x = document.forms["myForm"]["ssn1"].value;
            var y = document.forms["myForm"]["ssn2"].value;
            if (x !== y ){
                alert("Social Security number does not match");
                return false;
            }

        }

      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column left" id="left"></div>
      <div class="column middle" id="middle">
        <h2 id = "vapheading">Please fill out the Following Form</h2>
          <div id = "form">
          <form class="contact-form__label" name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
            <table id = "table">
              <tr>
                  <td>First Name:* <br/><input type="text" name="firstname" id="fname" required/></td>
                  <td>Middle Name: <br/><input type="text" name="middlename" id="mname" /></td>
                  <td>Last Name:* <br/><input type="text" name="lastname" id="lname" required/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Suffix: <br/><input type="text" name="suffix" id="suffix" /></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
            <tr>
              <td>SSN:* <br/><input class="required-input" id="ssn1" maxlength="9" type="password" name="ssn1" required/></td>
              <td>Verify SSN:* <br/><input class="required-input" id="ssn2" maxlength="9" type="password" name="ssn2" required/></td>
              <td>Date of Birth:* <br/><input type="date" name="birthday"  id="bday" required/></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Place of Birth - City:* <br/><input type="text" name="city" id="city"  required/></td>
              <td>Place of Birth - State: <br/><input type="text" name="state"  id="state" ></td>
              <td>Place of Birth - Country:* <br/><select name="country"  id="country" required>
                <option value="">Choose Here</option>
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option><option value="Albania">Albania</option><option value="Algeria">Algeria</option><option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
                <option value="Angola">Angola</option><option value="Antigua & Deps">Antigua & Deps</option><option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
                <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option><option value="Australia">Australia</option><option value="Austria">Austria</option>
                <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option><option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option><option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
                <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option><option value="Barbados">Barbados</option><option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
                <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option><option value="Belize">Belize</option><option value="Benin">Benin</option>
                <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option><option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option><option value="Bosnia Herzegovina">Bosnia Herzegovina</option>
                <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option><option value="Brazil">Brazil</option><option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
                <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option><option value="Burkina">Burkina</option><option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
                <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option><option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option><option value="Canada">Canada</option>
                <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option><option value="Central African Rep">Central African Rep</option><option value="Chad">Chad</option>
                <option value="Chile">Chile</option><option value="China">China</option><option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
                <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option><option value="Congo">Congo</option><option value="Congo {Democratic Rep}">Congo {Democratic Rep}</option>
                <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option><option value="Croatia">Croatia</option><option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
                <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option><option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option><option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
                <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option><option value="Dominica">Dominica</option><option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
                <option value="East Timor">East Timor</option><option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option><option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
                <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option><option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option><option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
                <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option><option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option><option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
                <option value="Finland">Finland</option><option value="France">France</option><option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
                <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option><option value="Georgia">Georgia</option><option value="Germany">Germany</option>
                <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option><option value="Greece">Greece</option><option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
                <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option><option value="Guinea">Guinea</option><option value="Guinea-Bissau">Guinea-Bissau</option>
                <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option><option value="Haiti">Haiti</option><option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
                <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option><option value="Iceland">Iceland</option><option value="India">India</option>
                <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option><option value="Iran">Iran</option><option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
                <option value="Ireland {Republic}">Ireland {Republic}</option><option value="Israel">Israel</option><option value="Italy">Italy</option>
                <option value="Ivory Coast">Ivory Coast</option><option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option><option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option><option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option><option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
                <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option><option value="Korea North">Korea North</option><option value="Korea South">Korea South</option>
                <option value="Kosovo">Kosovo</option><option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option><option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                <option value="Laos">Laos</option><option value="Latvia">Latvia</option><option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
                <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option><option value="Liberia">Liberia</option><option value="Libya">Libya</option>
                <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option><option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option><option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
                <option value="Macedonia">Macedonia</option><option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option><option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
                <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option><option value="Maldives">Maldives</option><option value="Mali">Mali</option>
                <option value="Malta">Malta</option><option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option><option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
                <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option><option value="Mexico">Mexico</option><option value="Micronesia">Micronesia</option>
                <option value="Moldova">Moldova</option><option value="Monaco">Monaco</option><option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
                <option value="Montenegro">Montenegro</option><option value="Morocco">Morocco</option><option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
                <option value="Myanmar, {Burma}">Myanmar, {Burma}</option><option value="Namibia">Namibia</option><option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
                <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option><option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option><option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
                <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option><option value="Niger">Niger</option><option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
                <option value="Norway">Norway</option><option value="Oman">Oman</option><option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                <option value="Palau">Palau</option><option value="Panama">Panama</option><option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
                <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option><option value="Peru">Peru</option><option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
                <option value="Poland">Poland</option><option value="Portugal">Portugal</option><option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
                <option value="Romania">Romania</option><option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option><option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
                <option value="St Kitts & Nevis">St Kitts & Nevis</option><option value="St Lucia">St Lucia</option><option value="Saint Vincent & the Grenadines">Saint Vincent & the Grenadines</option>
                <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option><option value="San Marino">San Marino</option><option value="Sao Tome & Principe">Sao Tome & Principe</option>
                <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option><option value="Senegal">Senegal</option><option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
                <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option><option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option><option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
                <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option><option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option><option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
                <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option><option value="South Africa">South Africa</option><option value="South Sudan">South Sudan</option>
                <option value="Spain">Spain</option><option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option><option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
                <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option><option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option><option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
                <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option><option value="Syria">Syria</option><option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
                <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option><option value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option><option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
                <option value="Togo">Togo</option><option value="Tonga">Tonga</option><option value="Trinidad & Tobago">Trinidad & Tobago</option>
                <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option><option value="Turkey">Turkey</option><option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
                <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option><option value="Uganda">Uganda</option><option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
                <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option><option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option><option value="United States">United States</option>
                <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option><option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option><option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
                <option value="Vatican City">Vatican City</option><option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option><option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
                <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option><option value="Zambia">Zambia</option><option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
              </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Citizenship:* <br/><select name="citizenship"  id="citixen" default required>
                              <option value="">Choose Here</option>
                              <option value="USCitizen">US Citizen</option>
                              <option value="greencard">Green Card</option>
                              <option value="H1B">H1B</option>
                              <option value="EAD">EAD</option>
                              <option value="Other">Other</option>
                          </select></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <br/><br/><button type="submit">Submit</button>

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column right" id="right"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="vap_script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter how you select an element,  by ID, className, name, etc, it still won't find it, if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: It does exist, the wrong selector is being used. You can see in the console that `document.getElementsByClassName('contact-form')` returns an empty result. Whereas when using the selector `contact-form__label`, it returns a result containing the form element.

Comment: Run the snippet @Keith

Comment: @Callam OP most likely pasted his vap_script.js into the snippet, this will fix the problem for the snippet but not his own environment.

Comment: Okay, but it still remains that the class name selector OP is using wouldn't return the form regardless, right?

Comment: Like,  @ChrisG said, unfortunately SO Snippets are hiding a common problem.  The DOM is always loaded when the snippet is run, but in production if you have a script in the HEAD, and try to access a DOM element it will fail.  His selector mismatch is indeed another problem.   So your solution mixed with moving the Script tag should solve the problem.

Comment: @Callam Yes, but your answer should address that fixing the `class` issue is not enough to solve the problem (it should imo also demonstrate that pasting the entire html into the HTML field instead of just the body contents is not required, even though the OP doing this pointed out an additional problem with his code)

Comment: @Callam I'm sorry that we keep picking on your answer, but what is that self executing closure going to fix? If that is in the head, it won't find the form. It will execute right away, not after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: That's okay, yes you're right, it does nothing – I thought it worked but I must have tested it in the snippet script window rather than in a script in the header.

Comment: If you do want to keep the script in the head, you could maybe use the `body.onload` event,  in more modern JS engines you could maybe even use the `async` or `defer` options.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this line at start of your JavaScript code:

```
var form = document.forms[0];
```

Now you can access the `form` variable.